# how to get string from

Tags: html, ruby, command-line-interface, nokogiri

I'm using nokogiri and scraped the entire

[Big Ten Conference](https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/seasons/2021.html)

How would I be able to only puts the Big Ten Conference?

```
require "open-uri"
class Scraper
    URL = "https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/seasons/2021.html"
   
def self.scrape_conference
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL))
    conference_main = doc.css("#conference-summary td.left a")
    conference_array = conference_main.text
      
    puts conference_array
end

def self.scrape_team
end
        
end

Scraper.scrape_conference
```

Comment: Can you be a little more specific, what is the problem you're having with this code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is the `conference_main` is a Array of Nokogiri::XML::Element so, if you only want get the first element of all list scraped one options is take the first element, for example:

```rb
require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"

class Scraper
  URL = "https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/seasons/2021.html"

  def self.scrape_conference
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL))
    conference_main = doc.css("#conference-summary td.left a")
    conference_first_item = conference_main.first.text
    puts conference_first_item
  end

  def self.scrape_tean; end
end


Scraper.scrape_conference
```

But if you want save all text of links into Array you can iterate on `conference_main` for example:

```rb
require "nokogiri"
require "open-uri"

class Scraper
  URL = "https://www.sports-reference.com/cbb/seasons/2021.html"

  def self.scrape_conference
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(URL))
    conference_array = doc.css("#conference-summary td.left a").map(&:text)
  end

  def self.scrape_tean; end
end

Scraper.scrape_conference
```